# Ensure percentages are between 0 and 1, inclusive (using a single function)

Tags: sql, oracle, math, select, oracle12c

I have percentages in a `condition` table:

```
create table condition (percent_decimal number(3,2));
insert into condition values (-0.01);
insert into condition values (0.1);
insert into condition values (1);
insert into condition values (1.1);
commit;

PERCENT_DECIMAL
---------------
          -0.01
             .1
              1
            1.1
```

I want to select the values, but modify them to present them as percentages between 0 and 1 (inclusive):

- Convert `-0.01` to `0`
- Leave `.1` as is
- Leave `1` as is
- Convert `1.1` to `1`

I can successfully do this using the [greatest](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm) and [least](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions075.htm) functions:

```
select
    percent_decimal,
    least(1,greatest(0,percent_decimal)) as percent_modified
from
    condition

PERCENT_DECIMAL PERCENT_MODIFIED
--------------- ----------------
          -0.01                0
             .1               .1
              1                1
            1.1                1
```

**However, I'm wondering if there is a more succinct way of doing this--with a single function.**

Comment: Perhaps think about an alternate approach - stop the data from getting in there in the first place with a check constraint `alter table condition add constraint chk check ( percent_decimal between 0 and 1)` or similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a single case expression:

```
select
    percent_decimal,
    case when percent_decimal < 0 then 0
         when percent_decimal > 1 then 1
         else percent_decimal
    end as percent_modified
from
    condition
/

PERCENT_DECIMAL PERCENT_MODIFIED
--------------- ----------------
          -0.01                0
             .1               .1
              1                1
            1.1                1
```

which is longer, but uses no functions, and I think it's clearer to someone coming along later what your logic is.